# How to run java gui in browser

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, browser, applet

I have this java gui that I made in NetBeans IDE 7.4, but is it possible if I want to see the program run from the browser? or should I make another one with java applet? I've try to make the html but when I double click it show that application error and show exception message, even though if I try to run it in Netbeans compiler it work properly. (I've set the java security to medium)

this is the html that I use for running the class

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><applet code="home" archive="web.jar"  width="590" height="530"></applet></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you make sure there is no security restrictions on running applets in your browser?

Comment: I've to run some java applet code and it worked on firefox that i use, but when i try to run the java gui it wont do the same

Comment: when you say "java gui" what exactly do you mean? Is it a application developed in Swing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Java Web Start` for deploying Java applications over the web. You can read about it [**here**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/).

Java applets allow you to embed java applications in the browser but it has security issues and other stuffs. More over, to use applet your application should extend the `Applet` class.